# Classical mechanics: Generating function of lagrangian submanifold

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism

I have a short question regarding the geometrical interpretation of the Hamilton-Jacobi-equation.

One has the geometric version of $H \circ dS = E$ as an lagrangian submanifold $L=im(dS)$, which is transverse to the fibers of $T^*Q$ and lies in the coisotropic submanifold $H^{-1}(E)$. Furthermore the pullback of the canonical one-form $\theta$ to L is exact.

The question is: Is L an **embedded** submanifold? I think if I have a solution S of the Hamilton-Jacobi-equation, then it generates an embedded submanifold $dS(Q)$. But have I have to use an embedded lagrangian submanifold to get an "analytical" solution or is an "normal" submanifold enough?

Comment: What is the meaning of the distinction you've made between embedded and "normal" submanifolds? Typically, a regular submanifold **is** an embedded submanifold. You may be using a specific definition? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold#Embedded_submanifolds

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ and $N$ be manifolds and $f: M \to N$ a diffeomorphism. The Lagrangian submanifold generated by $f$ is

$$ Y_f = \{(x,y,d_x f, d_y f); \, (x,y) \in M \times N\} \, ,$$

where

$$d_x f = (df)|_{T^*_x M} \quad \text{and} \quad d_y f = (df)|_{T^*_y N} \, . $$

Define the *twist* of $Y_f$ by

$$ Y_f^\sigma = \{(x,y,d_x f, -d_y f); \, (x,y) \in M \times N\} \, .$$

**Theorem:** $f$ is a generating function of the symplectomorphism $\phi: T^*M \to T^*N$ iff $Y_f^\sigma$ is its graph. This condition is equivalent to solving

$$ \phi(x,\xi) = (y,\eta) \Longleftrightarrow \xi = d_x f \quad \text{and} \quad \eta = -d_y f \, ,$$

which is a property of generating functions that can also be derived from the Hamilton-Jacobi (HJ) equation.

This digression shows that not all Lagrangian submanifolds can be associated to generating functions. Since we are talking about differential manifolds and submanifolds that are graphs of diffeomorphisms, the topology of such submanifolds is inherited from the base.

In resume: the submanifold itself is not enough to guarantee that the HJ equation can be solved, but a solution to the HJ equation will definitely provide a well behaved Lagrangian submanifold.

Comment: " ...differential manifolds and submanifolds that are graphs of diffeomorphisms..." May you please elaborate on this point? What does it mean to have a graph of a diffeomorphism (assuming I know what each is individually)?

Comment: I only saw your comment now. Sorry. A function $f:M \to M$ is a diffeomorphism if, for all $\phi: M \subset U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ charts in the atlas associated to $M$, its local expression $F = \phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a diffeomorphism. The graph of a function is the pair $G(f) = (x,f(x)) $, for $x$ in the domain of $f$. You can then separate between the graph of the diffeomorphism $f$ and the graph of its local expression $F$, which are different things (for a general manifold, the latter is the one that you can draw on paper).

Comment: Ah I see. By graph you mean the graph of a function, not an abstract graph. Thank you